# ModuleNotFoundException error in JBoss

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss

I'm running my project with jboss 7.1.1 and it's giving flowing exception.

```
09:21:52,354 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.module.service."deployment.PortalDeCompras-SrvEAR.ear.PortalDeCompras-Srv.jar".main: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service."deployment.PortalDeCompras-SrvEAR.ear.PortalDeCompras-Srv.jar".main: JBAS018759: Failed to load module: deployment.PortalDeCompras-SrvEAR.ear.PortalDeCompras-Srv.jar:main
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:91) [jboss-as-server-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: com.is2.log4j.portalCompras:main
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:1030) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1386) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1414) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:242) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:70) [jboss-as-server-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    ... 5 more
```

This is my application.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd"
id="Application_ID" version="6">
<display-name>PortalDeCompras</display-name>
<module>
    <ejb>PortalDeCompras-Srv.jar</ejb>
</module>
<module>
<web>
  <web-uri>PortalDeComprasWeb.war</web-uri>
  <context-root>PortalWeb</context-root>
</web>
</module>
</application>
```

Please, can any please help me? I have lot hurry !!!

Answer (score 2):

You should put the required jar (this missing one) file as a module into JBOSS_HOME/modules/com/is2/log4j/portalCompras/main and define a module.xml for it.